# Show the set $S_a$ is a mooth surface, find its dimension and if is connected. Plus find the minimum of elements of the atlas.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, surfaces

I have trouble with these exercises. I hope you can give me advice o how to try them or books where these themes are explained better.

> For each of the following sets determine for which values of the parameter $a$, $S_a$ is a smooth surface, its dmension and if is connected:
> a) $S_a=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2-y^2=a\}$;     b)$S_a=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2-y^2=a\}$; c)$S_a=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=z^2+a\}$.

And the same for this one:

> How many maps (or letters) is the minimal quantity in order to form an atlas of the following surfaces:
> a) $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: z^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$; b) $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\}$

The definitions of the notes of the teacher are the following:

> $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a topological surface of dimension $k$ if every point of $S$ has a neighborhood $U$ in $S$ homeomorphic to an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^k$.  $(U,\xi)$ with $U$ an open subset in $S$ and $\xi$ a homeomorphism of $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a letter (or map) in $S$.
> A family $A$ of maps in $S$ is an atlas of $S$ if $\bigcup\{U:(U,\xi)\in A\}=S$; $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth surface of dimension $k$ of class $C^l$ if $S$ is a topological surface of dimnsion $k$ and $S$ has an atlas of class $C^l$.

What I tried for the first exercise was to take a point of the set, which clearly is an hyperbole and try to find an open set conataining the point and a function defined on it with rank in $\mathbb{R}$ such that it was a homeomorphism but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem? have you seen the proof that manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be defined by solutions of systems equations of the form $F(x) = 0$, where F is a vector valued function $\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $D_{F} $ having maximal rank?

Comment: @Tom Ariel  The first yes but the second not. Can you tell me which book is good for the manifolds?

Comment: The matter is that this subject is supposed to be an elemntal course of integral calculus in several variables and regularly these themes are not studied until an advanced course of analysis or something like that

Comment: You can easily "construct" a manifold structure on the solution set in the following matter: use the implicit function theorem locally to find local parametrizations of the solution set. Note that these local parametrizations can be used to define an atlas on your set.